# Stream audio to file

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, streaming

I have a SoC device that I would like to use to make audio recordings automatically when powered on. Importantly, the device is powered off just by cutting the power supply. Therefore I need to include in my startup script an application that streams audio data directly to file (like `dd`) in an audio format that is playable up to the last moment of recording before powering off. I imagine this is easily accomplished but I'm not familiar with multimedia  programming.